# Can individual forces be regarded as momentum flows?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, momentum

Net force on an object can be defined in two ways equivalently (from a classical point of view):

$$\vec{F} = m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$$

Looking at the last expression (definition in terms of momentum), I tried to extend this definition for single forces (not just the net resultant on an object). This interpretation might not have any physical significance, but it does help to give a new perspective on force. I just wanted to know if it is theoretically sound (ie does not contradict the established theory).

We can regard each force as transporting momentum from the object applying it to the object it is applied, so for instance if I apply a force of $10N$ to a block on a frictionless surface, I transport $10 N\cdot m$ of momentum per second to the block.

This is of course simple, if only single forces are involved. Consider a situation with multiple forces.

Say we are in a spaceship floating in space. Inside a room on the spaceship, we have a block attached with a string to the wall. I pull on the block with $10 N$ (by pushing against the floor), the string will pull on the block with $10N$, the wall will pull on the string with $10N$. In turn I will push the floor with a force $10N$ so there is no net force on the spaceship which is in agreement with the fact that momentum is conserved (and hence can be regarded as a quantity that can flow).

Now, if we look in terms of momentum flows, I transfer $10 N\cdot m$ of momentum to the block, simultaneously, the string transfers the same amount of momentum from the block per second, the wall in turn transfers the same amount of momentum from the string and I, by pushing on the floor remove the same amount of momentum from it.

In this way, a continuous cycle of momentum transfer is set up, which begins as soon as I start pulling on the block, analogous to an electric circuit.

This methodology of thinking has really helped me in my conception of forces. So far, I have not encountered any contradictions. So my question is:

> Can individual forces be regarded as momentum flows? If not, why not?

Comment: (Newtonian) force **is** momentum flow. That said, while your title asks a question, the body contains no question. Do you simply mean to ask the question in the title? (Then the answer is a simple, unequivocal *yes*)

Comment: @ACuriousMind: The body does contain a question of sorts. I was presenting a 'theory' and I wanted criticism on it.

Comment: That's not the kind of question/phrasing we want here. From the [help center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): *"To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where [...] there is no actual problem [read: question] to be solved."*

Answer (score 3):

Even classically, forces arise from field being propagated at the speed of light. A physically relevant object is the energy-stress tensor, whose components represent energy density and momentum current density, so indeed momentum can be interpreted as a current that is conserved over time (as a consequence of symmetries).

This point of view is also important for another important aspect in physics which is *locality*, since interaction between the field and particles happens at specific points in space-time. Thinking in terms of fields is a good way to remove the notion of action at a distance from physics, and solve the apparent paradoxa where the momentum doesn't seem to be conserved. This is fixed by the fact that a field can be thought as a *reservoir* of energy and momentum that gets transmitted through waves to the objects it interacts with.

On a quantum level, the interaction is interpreted as mediated by quanta associated to the field, which bear energy and momentum (e.g. photons for electrodynamics, gluons for quantum chromodynamics, the graviton for the gravitational effects of general relativity etc...).